# Find TM superscript in python 2 using regex

Tags: python, regex, superscript

My text file includes "SSS™" as one of its words and I am trying to find it using regular expression. My problem is with finding ™ superscript. My code is:

```
import re
path='G:\python_code\A.txt'
f_general=open(path, 'r')
special=re.findall(r'\U2122',f_general.read())
print(special)
```

but it doesn't print anything. How can I fix it?

Comment: PostScript is a programming language, and what you are describing is a **superscript** not a postscript.

Comment: thanks @KenS for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the encoding of your file.  Try this:

```
import re

path = "g:\python_code\A.txt"
f_general=open(path, "r", encoding="UTF-16")
data = f_general.read()
special=re.findall(chr(8482), data)
print(special)
print(chr(8482))
```

Note I'm using the decimal value for Trade mark.  This is the site I use:
https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

So, open the file you have in notepad.  Do a `save as` and choose encoding `unicode` and this should all work.  Working with extended ascii can be a hassle.  I am using Python 3.6 <strike>but I *think* this should still work in 2.x</strike>

Note when it prints out the `chr(8482)` in your command line it will probably just be a `T`, at least that is what I get in windows.

**update**

Try this for Python 2 and this should capture the word before trademark:

```
import re

with open("g:\python_code\A.txt", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read().decode("UTF-16")
regex = re.compile("\S+" + chr(8482))
match = re.search(regex, data)
if match:
    print (match.group(0))
```

Comment: Thanks @sniperd. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. When I run your code an error occurs that
    f_general=open(path, "r", encoding="UTF-16")
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this 
    function.
When I delete encoding="UTF-16" it says
    special=re.findall(chr(8482), data)
    ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256).
Moreover I want to find something like SSS™ or AA™. I mean I don't want to just find a character, and I don't know if even I can find the ™ character how can I find something like SSS™ in general

Comment: @Morteza Cool, that makes sense.  I think encoding must only work in python3.  I've updated the answer to include what I _think_ will work for python2 and capturing the word in front of tm.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sniperd for your help. Unfortunately, the error still says "ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)".

Comment: @Morteza Darn it, I don't have access to python 2.x to test it out.  If you could get python 3.x installed somewhere, this will work.